# First line of PHP while loop doesn't echo to screen

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

In the following section of code.  I'm checking my `$email_count` and output one of two things.  This works fine.  The problem is in the while loop.  It doesn't echo out the first record.

```
// Get existing emails in system
      $email_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `massmail`");
      $row2 =mysql_fetch_array($email_data);
      $email_count = mysql_num_rows($email_data);

// Get the campaign name for existing emails      
      $latest_campaign = $row2['campaign_id'];
      $latest_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM campaign WHERE `id`='$latest_campaign'");
      $latest_row = mysql_fetch_array($latest_data);
      $latest_name= $latest_row['name']; 

// Display Options depending on availability of emails,       
          if($email_count ==0){
                echo "upload new file";


                        }else{
            echo "<span class=\"text_1\">The following <strong>".$email_count."</strong> emails are in the system for <strong>".$latest_name."</strong> campaign.<br><br>";
            echo "<div class=\"rounded-corners1\" id=\"latest_emails\" align=\"left\" style=\"overflow: auto; height: 200px; width:250px; \" >";

// THIS IS WHERE I OUTPUT TO SCREEN BUT THE FIRST RECORD DOESN'T OUTPUT.    

            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($email_data)){
                echo $row2['email'].'<br/>';
                    }
            echo "<br/></span></div><br/>";
            ?>
        <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
          <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#336699" class="rounded-corners1" ><span class="white_text">Delete Existing Emails and Upload New File for<br />
<strong><br />
<?php echo $campaign_selected; ?></strong></span><br />
              <br />
               <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'>
               <input type="hidden" name="campaign_id" id="campaign_id" value='<?php echo $campaign_id; ?>'  />
               <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the existing list?');" value="Continue >>" />
          <br />
        </form>
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#336666" class="rounded-corners1" >
               <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="mm_send_main_3.php">
                 <span class="white_text">Re-Send Message to<br />
                 the above list for<br />

<strong><br /><?php echo $latest_name; ?></strong></span><br />
<br />
               <input type="hidden" name="campaign_id" id="campaign_id" value='<?php echo $latest_campaign; ?>'  />
               <input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to process the existing list?');" value="Continue >>" />
          <br />
        </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
<?php
};
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure there's at least one record?

Comment: FYI: mysql is deprecated, consider switching to mysqli or pdo http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
  $email_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `massmail`");
  $row2 =mysql_fetch_array($email_data);

  ... lots of code ...

  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($email_data)){
```

That first `fetch` call right after you run the query fetches the first row of the result. As soon as you reach the `while()` call, that first `$row2` result is destroyed and lost.

As eleazan points out below, you can reverse the loop into a `do { ... } while()` instead.

```
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($email_data);
... do stuff
do {
   start output here
while ($row2 = msyql_fetch_array($email_data));
```

This will "preserve" that first row of data for your first iteration around the loop.

Comment: Adding to the answer... you can use do...while() for fix your problem fetching ;) http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

Comment: Phenomenal!!! Thanks Mark B.  Worked like a charm.  I check your answer as accepted, I hope this question helps other people as well.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks! I must remember to use do --- while more!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this before the while loop

```
mysql_data_seek($row2,0);
```

Each time you call a function like `mysql_fetch_array`, you are moving the internal row pointer within the MySQL result. As you've already called `mysql_fetch_array`, it has shifted the pointer thus not returning the first row within your loop

Answer (score 1):

Here's your issue:

```
 $latest_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM campaign WHERE `id`='$latest_campaign'");
 $latest_row = mysql_fetch_array($latest_data);

....  

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($email_data)){
```

You're calling mysql_fetch_array right after your query; this loads the first record, and moves the pointer on to the next one.

In your loop, you're calling it again, and since the pointer is currently pointing at the second record, it starts outputting from there.